# I have sidenav. when i used <i> tag inside <a> tag then display none property not working on last .menu-icons class. Pl

Tags: html, css

I have sidenav. when i used  tag inside  tag then display none property not working on last .menu-icons class. If i not use  tag display none property is working. Basiclly i want an image show on hover and default image should be hide.

HTML

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" >
     <a href="#" class="mt-3">
        <embed src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/271/271888.svg" class="menu-icons">
        <embed src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2/2204.svg" class="menu-icons">
          Dashboard</a>
      <a (click)="toggle = !toggle">
        <embed src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/784/784746.svg" class="menu-icons">
        <embed src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/971/971646.svg" class="menu-icons">
          Reports <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
    .sidenav {
      width: 300px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 4;
      top: 80px;
      bottom:0;
      left: 0px;
      background-color: white;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding: 10px;
      transition: 0.5s;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 3px #ccc;
      border-radius: 0 20px;
    }

    /* The navigation menu links */
    .sidenav a {
      padding: 15px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #818181;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
      transition: 0.3s ease-in, .7s ease-out;
      cursor: pointer;
    }


    .sidenav a .menu-icons:last-child{display: none;}
    .sidenav a:hover {
      color: #fff;
      background: #0098DB;
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .sidenav a:hover .menu-icons:last-child{display: block;}
    .sidenav a:hover .menu-icons:first-child{display: none;}
    .menu-icons {
     height: 20px;
     width: 20px;
     margin-right: 25px;
     display: block;
    }


Please check fiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/jhmf5gv1/
```

Answer (score 0):

No t sure that's what you want, but to hide icons by default and display on hover, here is how you can do: https://jsfiddle.net/x741n0jv/2/

You don't need to have a double icon.

CSS

```
.sidenav a .menu-icons {display: none;}
.sidenav a:hover .menu-icons{display: block;}



.menu-icons {
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 margin-right: 25px;
 /* display: block; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Because it's considered i as last-child of an element.
So remove i tag or place it on top or middle.
Like this

```
<a (click)="toggle = !toggle">
<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
<embed src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/784/784746.svg" class="menu-icons">
<embed src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/971/971646.svg" class="menu-icons">
  Reports</a>
```

Comment: why? Unless i had specify that which one is last child.

Comment: Yes, but as per DOM, it's not the last-child of <a> tag. Last-child means parent last element but in this case, <i> tag is last-child. Otherwise, you target like this
a:last-child .menu-icons:nth-last-child(2).

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this to your css:

```
.sidenav a:hover .menu-icons{display: block;}
.sidenav a .menu-icons{display: none;}
.menu-icons {
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 margin-right: 25px;
}
```